# How to update a variable that was declared outside a promise inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, promise

In my component, I have a variable called `destination` and I assign it as an empty string. I then have a function that returns a promise and I pass the response to another function where I then use the returned object in an `Object.assign`. I use the new object to update the `destination` variable I created outside the promise.

```js
render() {
        return (
            <div className='destinations-container'>
                {
                    Object.keys(this.state.destinations).map((id) => {
                        var destination = "";
                        getFormSchema(this.state.destinations[id].product_type)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    let defaultConfig = setDefaultConfig(response.data);
                    destination = Object.assign(defaultConfig, this.state.destinations[id]);
                });
                        return <Widget name={destination.name}
                                       textlinks={this.createWidgetTextLinks(destination)}
                                       state={getDestinationState(this.state.metadata[id] || {})}>
                            <WidgetInfo>
                                {widgetOverviewStaticInformation(destination, this.state.productList)}
                                {metadataOverviewItemsToShow(this.state.metadata[id] || {})}
                            </WidgetInfo>
                            <EditDestinationForm destination={destination}/>;
                        </Widget>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The problem is that the destination variable remains as `""` even after assigning it the object returned from `Object.assign` within the promise. This leads me to believe that the `destination` variable inside the promise and the `destination` variable I assigned as an empty string outside the promise are two separate things.

How do I update the variable I declared as an empty string inside the promise?

Comment: Why are the strings not in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The `destination` variable may have the behavior you expect it to have.

I ask you this question : how do you know `destination` isn't updated ?

- Did you open a debugger and put a breakpoint inside the `then` callback ?
- Or did you conclude that based on the value rendered inside you browser window ?

In that second case, I'd like you to note that **your second return is also outside the promise** :

It certainly does render the Widget component before the promise resolve.

Comment: So I should put the widget in the promise?

Comment: I woudl say yes, without forgetting to add a `key` property on it. But I don't think that a Promise inside a component template is really a good practice. **You should instead use the parent component's `state` property and `this.setState()` method when your promise resolve.**

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue: when the method in the map returns, the promise did not resolve (they are asynchronous). I suggest you to use a different approach by using the internal state of the component (updated on the promise callback):

```js
// this can be in any method in the class, not just in render (it's better not to have it in render).
Promise.all(
    Object.keys(this.state.destinations)
        .map(id => getFormSchema(this.state.destinations[id].product_type))
).then(decoratedDestinations => this.setState({decoratedDestinations}));

//in the render:
return (
    <div className='destinations-container'>
        {this.state.decoratedDestinations.map(decoratedDestination => (
            <Widget name={decoratedDestination.name} ... >
                ...
            </Widget>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

In this way when the promises resolve react will automatically re-render your component with all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

`Destination` is being updated, it's just not being shown. You're returning from that function before the promise is finished so it'll render with whatever value it has. I agree with @imrok, you shouldn't have that promise within the render. Have the promise outside it and have it update the component's state when it finishes, that will cause a re-render with your desired value.